# How can I check error notifications on Postfix are correctly being sent?

Tags: postfix

I've recently configured a brand new Postfix server (latest version) on Debian 11, it's working great but on the old installation I used to receive an email whenever something went wrong when sending/receiving an email via Postfix. On the main configuration I've set the following parameters, thing is, I've yet to receive any error email from Postfix and I am sure (from experience) that every single day at least a few messages don't get through.

```
delay_notice_recipient = myemail@mydomain.com
bounce_notice_recipient = myemail@mydomain.com
2bounce_notice_recipient = myemail@mydomain.com
error_notice_recipient = myemail@mydomain.com
```

First of all, is the configuration above correct? Am I missing something? Also any way to trigger an error? I've tried to send an email via telnet to a wrong recipient but I didn't get any notifications back.

Thanks.

Comment: Just send a message to `nonexistingmailbox@mydomain.example`?

Answer (score 0):

You may have configured a recipient for a notification class that is not enabled in any relevant postfix service. Notably, the mailbox specified in `bounce_notice_recipient` only receives headers of rejected messages when `bounce` appears in your `notify_classes`.

Also, you will have to review postfix logs to see whether this works. Because you won't be notified of errors with delivering to a non-local mailbox.. if your error notification recipient is affected by the same problem affecting non-local delivery. If this is the case, you would likely be able to locate the problem in log messages containing the obvious keywords (such as warning, error, 2bounce, ..).